# Connect Azure data explorer cluster to an application Insight cluster

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, kql

I found a way to connect azure data explorer to an application Insight cluster, Now I want to connect an azure data explorer cluster to an application Insights cluster in order to use (enable) a python plugin into KQL query, but i can't find a solution !!

based on this doc, I connected ADX to appInsight cluster https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/query-monitor-data (it works well), but i need to use a python plugin to query appInsight within ADX, to do that i must create an ADX cluster (OK) than enabling python plugin (OK) but I didn't find a way to connect this cluster to an appInsight cluster. IngestData does not offer a solution for that

[image: 1]

i want to use python code within ADX KQL request

Comment: I dont get what you are missing? It should not matter what SDK/language you are using, you should still be able to write KQL for cross-resource queries like described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/query-monitor-data#cross-query-of-your-log-analytics-or-application-insights-workspace-and-the-azure-data-explorer-native-cluster

Comment: I want to use python code in an ADX cluster to query an appInsights cluster